# Automator or Applescript, detect a new file in folder

Tags: file, osx-lion, applescript, automator

I am trying to write something that will detect a new file in a certain specified directory. I preferably would like this script to continue running indefinitely, and whenever I see a new file, I can copy it and move it somewhere else. I know this has to be possible, because dropbox does it, but I just do not know how to get this working or where to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for (to spawn off Applescripts when adding new files into a "hot folder") is called "Folder Actions", and there are a number of tutorials that can be found online that should point you in the right direction.

For example, here is one: ["AppleScript: Exploring the power of Folder Actions, part I"](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/02/16/applescript-exploring-the-power-of-folder-actions-part-i/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example of a folder action. You should save the script in ~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts .

```
    on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles

    -- This should make the folder action wait until large files have finished copying to the folder
    set fSizes to {0}
    repeat
        tell application "System Events" to set end of fSizes to size of theFolder
        if (item -1 of fSizes) = (item -2 of fSizes) then exit repeat
        delay 1
    end repeat

    -- If you want to do something with each file ...
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        -- your code goes here  
    end repeat

end adding folder items to
```

Keep in mind that if your script saves anything to the target folder, the folder action will be triggered again.