# applescript, folder action, move copied items fails, timing issue?

Tags: applescript, move, timing, finder

Please help, I can't think of a fix for this.

A folder action is meant to do this for each file copied into a folder:

1. Derive a subfolder name, and a new filename.
2. Create subfolder.
3. Move file into it.
4. Rename subfolder and file.

Files are copied from a different volume and are usually 500…1500 MB.

**Problem:** The moving step *(step 3)* in the folder action script fails if the files are that large and their number is `>1`
and they are copied from a different volume.

The script works fine when copying: small files, or from the same volume, or only one file.

In a test, all of 200 Alias' were correctly processed, but only 23 of 512. This is not a problem, the number of `added_items` is usually `<10` and unlikely to ever be `>50`. But it may help targeting the issue.

I suspected a timing issue, but all attempts to fix it using generous `timeout`'s didn't work.

The script (note - before trying, set the regex in the `do shell script` lines to something workable):

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    repeat with the_item in added_items
        with timeout of 3600 seconds

            tell application "Finder"
                if kind of the_item is not "Folder" then

                    repeat -- wait until item is copied. Thanks to original coder on the WWW.
                        set {size:fileSize, busy status:Busy} to (info for (the_item))
                        if not Busy and (fileSize is greater than 0) then exit repeat
                        delay 1
                    end repeat

                    with timeout of 600 seconds
                        set new_folder_name to do shell script "echo '" & (name of the_item) ¬
                            & "' | sed -E 's/llooongRegex/replace/g'"
                        set new_item_name to do shell script "echo '" & (name of the_item) ¬
                            & "' | sed -E 's/otherRegex/replace/g'"

                        set new_folder to (make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:(new_folder_name & "-temp")}) as alias -- "-temp" in case new folder and file will have the same name

                        move file the_item to folder new_folder -- <== fails if ((added_items >1) AND (files big, tested with 0.5…1.5GB) AND (copied from different volume))   ==> Timing issue? 

                        set name of (first item of (get contents of new_folder)) to new_item_name

                        set name of new_folder to new_folder_name

                    end timeout

                end if
            end tell

        end timeout
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

P.S.: is `folder-action` frequent enough for a tag?

Comment: Be aware that any mutation of the hot folder (adding item, creating folder, renaming folder) triggers the folder action again which could cause some *hiccup*.

Comment: Yes, maybe the number of triggered actions could be a problem. But for small files at least 200 items are processed OK.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the `repeat -- wait until item is copied....` clause with a simple `delay 60`, the script works. So it is a timing problem.

Waiting for the target folder to stop changing size as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894252/5309571) works as long as only 1 file copying (bunch of files dropped) is running. Two or more drag'n drops, and it *hiccups* again (nice word, @vadian!).

Ditto when checking for the size of individual added items to remain constant.